# HTTP status code for not allowing users to like their own posts?

Tags: http

I was in the process of programming a backend API for a blog-like website. Users may create posts, but they may not like their own posts. What would the HTTP code be for users should not be able to like their own posts?

Would it be code 400 bad request? Or would it be duplicated resource?

Comment: https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with [403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

"The request contained valid data and was understood by the server, but the server is refusing action."